# How to remove single quote in python list

Tags: arrays, pandas, list, dataframe, numpy

I would like to remove the single quotes from a list

Creating loop:

```
results = []
for k in range(1,number_of_observation+2):
results += ['X'+str(k)]

results
```

Output :

```
['X1','X2','X3','X4','X5','X6','X7','X8','X9','X10','X11','X12','X13','X14','X15','X16','X17','X18']
```

Actually each element in the list contains numpy array like this :

```
X1 = array([ 5.29869582e+03,  4.78138124e+03,  4.66993519e+03,  4.63760715e+03,
             4.24625776e+03,  6.82121026e-13,  3.67310328e+03,  3.62922983e+03,
             4.67551867e+03, -2.01596513e+03,  5.17998388e+03,  0.00000000e+00,
             5.44605355e+03,  4.51697631e+03,  4.62300856e+03,  4.44902873e+03])

X2 = array([ 5.15984732e+03,  3.69964719e+03,  4.88607026e+03,  5.06762424e+03,
             4.54623661e+03,  9.09494702e-13,  4.04998815e+03,  3.91555776e+03,
             5.07698709e+03, -1.11066480e+03,  4.49209767e+03,  4.54747351e-13,
             4.97724688e+03,  4.24955479e+03,  4.72048717e+03,  5.58904656e+03])
```

And i want to create dataframe from it

```
Final = pd.DataFrame(data = [results], columns= column_name)
Final
```

Desire output :

[image: Correct Dataframe]

But it gave me output like this :

[image: Incorrect Dataframe]

Comment: You intentionally made a list of strings, with `'X'+str(k)`.  The quote is the normal display of a string.  If you want a list of arrays, why don't you use `[X1, X2, X3, ...]`?  Don't be afraid to type all those variables.  In Python there's a very real difference between a variable name and a string.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj anyway thanks for your feedback, I've tried your method and the output works well when I type the list of [X1, X2, X3, ...] manually, I am just trying to make the code less typing and editing as possible, because this code will be used frequently with different shape of dataset

Comment: loop through all variables('x1', 'x2'), use evaluate function to get it's value...

Comment: @VinayG YOU MADE MY DAY DUDE, Thanks in advance, it works like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use eval function on the result list.Instead of just `[results]` use list comprehension as in the image.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can store each element as list of key value pairs, having key as X1 and value as floating point list.

So from list of dictionary you can iterate over keys and values seperately.